# Fixing last commit with 'git commit --amend' produces new commit without updating branch

Tags: git

I had the following situation as shown by `$ git log --pretty=oneline --all --graph`:

```
* 7248796 (HEAD, feature)
| * 9231616 (tag: v0.1, master)
|/
```

I needed to change 'readme.txt' file what was included in last commit 7248796.

```
$ git add readme.txt
$ git commit --amend --no-edit
```

It produced a new commit but did not move `feature`:

```
* da79188 (HEAD)
| * 7248796 (feature)
|/  
| * 9231616 (tag: v0.1, master)
|/
```

Why did this happen? Is there any chance somehow to include this last commit in `feature`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are in a "detached HEAD" state, i.e. HEAD pointed to commit `7248796` directly, not to branch `feature` and then indirectly to commit `7248796`.

Normally (without detached HEAD) the output of `git log` would have looked like

```
7248796 (HEAD -> feature)
```

instead of

```
7248796 (HEAD, feature)
```

That is why after `git commit --amend`, the new commit `da79188` was only pointed to by HEAD, but not by commit `feature`.

You can repair your situation by making `feature` point to `da79188` and HEAD point to `feature` again:

```
git checkout -B feature
```

giving you

```
* da79188 (HEAD -> feature)
| * 7248796 [abandoned, not shown in git log]
|/  
| * 9231616 (tag: v0.1, master)
|/
```

Comment: Rather than the checkout/hardreset pair, just re-hang the label without the worktree churn, for instance with `git checkout -B feature` .

Answer (score 1):

> It doesn't make sense to make a new commit

Yes it does. The first law of what Git is, is that commits are absolutely immutable. Otherwise the integrity of the history would be in great danger.

Two commits with different messages must therefore be two *different* commits and must have different hashes. Two commits with the same hash, conversely, are guaranteed to be one and the same commit, with the same message, contents, and parents, not only in your repo but in every repo on Earth. Only because of this rule are pushing and fetching coherently possible.

Moreover, the hash is in part based on the message, thus helping to guarantee this rule.

Comment: And please read https://www.biteinteractive.com/picturing-git-conceptions-and-misconceptions/

Comment: Thanks ! The meaning and necessity of commits is not a question of this topic. I removed that sentence so it wouldn't cause more confusion.

Comment: Yes it is. You said (although you have now removed it) "It doesn't make sense to make a new commit to fix one punctuation mark". That's incorrect. No matter _what_ your situation is, amending a commit will make a new and different commit.

Comment: I already know that and therefore that was not asked. Read carefully - I wanted to use git --amend to replace commit. I understand and agree that naming that git option is somewhat confusing.